# Can color of image be improved upon

Tags: image-processing

I am not sure if this is the place to post this type of question.

I purchased a USB Digital camera - specifically for outdoor usage (eBay item from China).

The quality of some of the colors -namely the green color comes out as purplish!

Assuming there is nothing I can do with the camera settings is it possible to enhance the colors to what it really should look like?

this is the image taken from that USB camera:

[image: USB image]

this is the image taken from my analogue camera:

[image: Analogue Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your camera does not have an infrared cut filter. This allows all 3 color channels to get extra exposure via the near IR range of the spectrum.

Some outdoor cameras have night mode which slides the IR cut out of the way to allow higher sensitivity in the dark. In daylight, the filter is returned so that only visible color light can enter the sensor.
See if your camera has such a switch.

Comment: The white/purple colors are typical (search for `"ir cut" image` in image search).  
Good luck with the seller.

Comment: :-) I see a solution involving Duck tape, eBay and something like this http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/52-mm-Infrared-Infra-Red-Filter-720nm-IR-720-ND-17-/191405029725?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item2c90a0f95d

Comment: That's an IR-Pass filter that cuts visible light. You need an IR-cut filter that cuts IR-light.

Comment: yes you are right, after googling it is common. So, unless this supports ir cut I assume i am always going to get a restricted range of colors?

Comment: Note that without this filter, although the colors are strange, the sensitivity of the camera is higher, including at low light conditions, such as at night.  
If you add the IR-Cut filter you are basically reducing the amount of light coming in, so that the camera will be less sensitive. If this is a security camera, sensitivity may be more important than correct colors.

Comment: hi, live view and security are both my concerns but i understand your point. Thanks for the education :)